# How to break a long string with underscore? material ui table cell

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, word-wrap, tablecell

I have a table with cells of really long strings that have underscore e.g:
**word_word_word_word_word_word_word_word**

and those cells overflow with other cells, but I would expect them to wrap like e.g: 
**word_word_word_
 word_word_word_
 word_word**

Like it happens when string contains a **dash** e.g:
**word-word-word-word-word-word-word-word**

result: **Word-word-word-
 word-word-word-
 word-word**

`wordWrap: "break-word"`and `wordBreak: "break-all"` - break the word which I don't want to happen...

Comment: what happen if you have a loong word without hyphen or underscore?

Comment: it overflows with other cell